# PHP_XLSwriter array output

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a bit of php code called PHP_XLSWriter.  It accepts an input, then outputs it to an Excel sheet.

Their example.php page does exactly what I want, and in it, there's a bit of code that determines what specifically gets exported:

```
    $data1 = array(

      array('2003','1','-50.5','2010-01-01 23:00:00'),
      array('2003','=B2', '23.5','2010-01-01 00:00:00'),
    );
```

I haven't written arrays like this exactly in the past, but I've passed my own array into this page through AJAX from a separate page.  *I'm not sure if it's important how I did this, but I'm happy to paste in that code if it is.*

When I try to execute the page using MY array, the page fails and my console is full of intelligible text.

I can't figure out why this is as the `var_dump` of our two arrays are exactly the same.

the original `var_dump($data1);`

```
          array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(4) {
                [0]=>
            string(4) "2003"
            [1]=>
            string(1) "1"
            [2]=>
            string(5) "-50.5"
            [3]=>
            string(19) "2010-01-01 23:00:00"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(4) {
            [0]=>
            string(4) "2003"
            [1]=>
            string(3) "=B2"
            [2]=>
            string(4) "23.5"
            [3]=>
            string(19) "2010-01-01 00:00:00"
          }
        }
```

the `var_dump()` when I set `$data1` equal to the array I've imported:

```
 array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "blah"
        [1]=>
        string(12) "two"
        [2]=>
        string(6) "0.0160"
        [3]=>
        string(6) "0.0173"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "blah"
        [1]=>
        string(14) "three"
        [2]=>
        string(6) "0.0085"
        [3]=>
        string(6) "0.0095"
      }
    }
```

and `echo gettype($data1);` outputs `array` for both of the strings.

What might I be doing to cause this to break?  I'm positive it has something to do with my array, as all else held equal, the code works.